# Sync local storage auth token status with the views

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-local-storage

I have two controller in angular js.

- **NavCtrl** which controls the navbar and shows logout button as needed
- **AuthCtrl** which is responsible for authentication and setting local storage

The problem that i am facing is everything works fine on setting the token and retrieving the same in both controllers.

But when i authenticate, i need to reload the page to see changes in NavCtrl because it takes the value when the page was rendered. Is there some way i can pass a notification to NavCtrl when there is a `login` or `logout` request to render changes accordingly ?

```
.controller 'AuthCtrl',($scope,User)->
    $scope.login = ()->
        User.auth $scope.username,$scope.password
        return
    return

.controller 'NavCtrl',($scope,User,$window)->
    $scope.is_authenticated = $window.localStorage.getItem "authFlag"
    console.log $window.localStorage.getItem "token"
    console.log $window.localStorage.getItem "authFlag"
    $scope.logout = ()->
        User.logout()
        $scope.is_authenticated = $window.localStorage.getItem "authFlag"
    return
```

`User` is factory that i defined and `authFlag` is `bool` that stores the auth status. Basically i want to listen to changes made in `authFlag`

Also if possible please comment if this is the best practices or i am doing something wrong over.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be resolved by adding a simple brodcast. Inside the user factory where the authentication happens, add

`$rootScope.$broadcast 'authEvt'`

and in `navCtrl` catch the broadcast using

`$rootScope.$on "authEvt",()->
        $scope.is_authenticated = $window.localStorage.getItem "authFlag"
        return`

This will reload the variables on change of localStorage event.

Comment: I think you should use router to switch views used for each case (/login and /main - after /login). Nav Bar should only be loaded right after /login

Comment: @VuQuyet navbar is same template dashboard and login page. I tried with $location.path also but even that was not working, i was getting a dashboard with login button on top. Only when i reloaded the app did i get logout button. The best way that i found online was to use events :)